# Is there a net pressure force on a pipe bend?

Tags: forces, pressure

Assume a pipe has wall thickness x. If the pressure inside and outside of the pipe bend is the same. Does it result in a non-zero net force on the pipe bend as the inner and outer areas differ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could ask the same for a hollow sphere with finite wall thickness, where the inner and outer areas also differ.

It's a bit easier in that case, because symmetry ensures that the forces by the pressurized regions are all in the radial direction. You could then divide the sphere in segments (like a soccer ball, for instance) and ask about the forces on one of the segments, see drawing:

[image: sphere]

As your question suggests, the forces from the inside and the outside may not be equal even if the pressure in those regions is the same. But there are also forces between adjacent segments where they join each other. I leave it to you to show that all of them are balanced!